# What is the one-point compactification of the Loch Ness Monster?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

The [Loch Ness Monster surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_monster_surface) is the noncompact orientable surface with one end accumulated by genus. If we take the one-point compactification of this surface <s>we get some surface with finite genus by the classification.</s> and get a manifold, it would have finite genus by the classification. This seems a little absurd.

What is the one-point compactification of the Loch Ness Monster, and in general, is there any intuition behind determining compactifications of surfaces with infinite genus?

Comment: The related link ['Compactification of Manifolds'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/compactification-of-manifolds) shows that a connected surface with infinite genus is not homeomorphic to an open subset of a compact surface; I would thus hazard that this is one of the cases where the one-point compactification does not produce a manifold. It appears there is a concept of [*stratifolds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratifold), which I don't quite understand, but may come into play here.

Comment: The bottom line is that the sentence "some surface with finite genus by the classification" is false.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Fair point — I edited my question to make my train of thought more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space (the one-point compactification) is not homeomorphic to any of the "standard" spaces you encounter in your topology classes (in particular, it is not a surface). Just call it "the one-point compactification of the Loch Ness Monster" (OPCOLNM), if you are looking for a nice name. As for the intuition of such spaces, I do not know what to say, there is none as far as I know. You may want to read some papers on the classification of noncompact surfaces, which uses compactifications to classify these. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117986/r-and-s-homeomorphic-riemann-surfaces-implies-exists-hr-to-s-orientat/2118622#2118622) for a reference and some discussion where I describe the "end compactification" in concrete terms.

Comment: I realise this isn't the purpose of the "comments section" but I just wanted to say - you answer all of my favourite questions (and all of my continuum theory questions earlier in the year). I really appreciate your contributions to MSE! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. What exactly are you referring to by “end compactification”? I’m not sure I see the connection in the linked answer or Richards’ paper.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology); without the end compactification you cannot understand the classification.

Comment: @Harambe: You are welcome!

Comment: @MoisheCohen Huh, I'm fairly familiar with the Richards' paper, and this is the first time I'm hearing about the end compactification. To get a better sense of this, correct me if I'm wrong -- it seems as though the end compactifcation of the LNM is the same as OPCOLNM, which would then just be a sphere with handles limiting to a particular point.

Comment: @SantanaAfton: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Okay, thank you!